# Prevent php from exposing include_path

Tags: php

Is there a way to prevent php from exposing the "include_path" value - server wide?

For example, if I do require("asdfasdf.php"); the error message results in saying what the include path is because it didnt find that file in the include path. I do not want php to expose this information.

Also, I'm aware there is a way to completely disable phpinfo(); However, is there a way to also hide the include_path value there instead?

Comment: Error reporting should always be off inproduction

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your question answered ;)

Comment: Even if error reporting is turned off on the server, whats stopping someone from making a script with error_reporting(E_ALL) and the attempting to include a nonexistent file?

Comment: If you have a kind of web-hosting service, your users shouldn't be able to influence or change your websites php.ini by creating their own scripts on their accounts. But that's way too broad for a SO question.

Comment: I dont see how. The php.ini settings are not forced at runtime. Any script via php code can change settings set in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

### Option One

You can use `@require("yourfile.php") or die("Couldn't include file")`, so it'll suppress the error message of require but still gives out an error.

---

### Option Two

The easiest way is to set error_reporting to zero inside the php.ini (or inside the script with `error_reporting(0);`) or at least don't display the errors (`ini_set('display_errors', 0);`).

Comment: Neither of these will work because a user could just create their own php file on account and set error reporting to whatever they want, or attempt to require a nonexistent file without the @suppressor to get the full error message... So I guess it cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Opion three**

ini_set('display_errors', 0); // Turns off error rapporting